# Assign macro in drop down list and run with button

Tags: list, excel, button, vba

I have created several macros that generates `ID`. Now I need to put them in a drop down list to be selected.

The idea is that I'll insert a button (let's call it `GENERATE`) and a drop down list 1 cell above the button. As the value changes in the drop down list, the `GENERATE` button will generate an `ID` of a different formula accordingly. Here is my codes although I'm not sure if they are right..

```
Sub GenerateID()
Dim macroName As String
macroName = Range("A4").Value

If macroName = NRIC Then
    Application.Run (GenerateNRICFIN)
ElseIf macroName = FIN Then
    Application.Run (GenerateFIN)
ElseIf macroName = RB Then
    Application.Run (GenerateRB)
ElseIf macroName = RB2 Then
    Application.Run (GenerateRB2)
ElseIf macroName = RB3 Then
    Application.Run (GenerateRB3)
ElseIf macroName = RB4 Then
    Application.Run (GenerateRB4)
ElseIf macroName = RB5 Then
    Application.Run (GenerateRB5)
ElseIf macroName = RC Then
    Application.Run (GenerateRC)
ElseIf macroName = RC2 Then
    Application.Run (GenerateRC2)
ElseIf macroName = RC3 Then
    Application.Run (GenerateRC3)
ElseIf macroName = RC4 Then
    Application.Run (GenerateRC4)
ElseIf macroName = RC5 Then
    Application.Run (GenerateRC5)
ElseIf macroName = RC6 Then
    Application.Run (GenerateRC6)
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! So your question is how get a drop down list in a cell of your spreadsheet? If yes, play around with the `Data Validation` function in the `Data` tab. Record what you are doing with the macro recorder so you can later include it in your code. Another option is to add a `ComboBox` element (entries are specified in its `RowSource` property).

Comment: -nhee I already got the drop-down list box part down! However it is not linking with the GENERATE button I am assigning this macro to.

Comment: Ok. I am guessing you are not specific enough when referencing the cell in your macro as you have no worksheet defined. Can you try `macroName = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet name").Range("A4").Value`?

Comment: -nhee Yes its working now! However, my other macros which generates the ID uses this function in the code. 
GenerateRandomNumber(intMinimum, intMaximum)
    Randomize
    GenerateRandomNumber = Int(((intMaximum - intMinimum + 1) * Rnd) + intMinimum)
My GenerateID macro now reads the generated ID from my other macros as a macro and cant function properly. It's hard to put it in words but what I mean is that the generated IDs are currently read as macros and isn't working properly. Do you know why? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Sorry, too confusing :-) "IDs are read as macros?"

Comment: -nhee For example.. if S9228922H is generated, it is read as a macro for some reason.. Then the error 1004 pops up as macro "S9228922H" is not found. It is supposed to be generated as an IDs for the output, but it is being read as a macro.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
Sub GenerateID()
Dim macroName As String
'macroName = Range("A4").Value 
macroName = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A4").Value

IF (macroName = "NRIC") then macroName = "NRICFIN"

Application.Run "Generate" & macroName

END Sub
```

Instead of all your if-statements.

Comment: Theres still an error where functions or variables are expected

Comment: now the word "Generate" is read as a macro, the same error 1004 pops out.

Comment: @junJie make break-point on `Application.Run` line by pressing F9, and run the macro, then when it stops over that line, by click on `macroName` and pressing Shift+F9 let me know the value of `macroName` ;).

Comment: the value is "out of context"

Comment: @JunJie "Out of context" is shown when you don't start the macro!

Comment: thats the thing... i'm trying to run the macro